# What color triangles did the different religious groups (those not Jews or JWs) wear in Nazi concentration camps?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler, holocaust

I was recently reading through Anton Gill's 1989 book ["The journey back from hell"](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL2512271W/The_Journey_Back_from_Hell_An_Oral_History) regarding the experiences of concentration camp survivors.

On p.31 of this book he mentions that

> There were several thousand priests, and members of religious orders
>   of both sexes, in the camps

I do realize, as is shown in [this other question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23997/what-were-the-52-kinds-of-victims-persecuted-by-the-nazis), that Jehovah's Witnesses wore the purple triangles. According to Anton Gill's book there were 6000 of them in the concentration camps and he says (on the same p.31) that "they attracted the special enmity of the Nazis". So I am not sure if these are the reasons why they had their own triangle color.

Anyway, presumably they were not the only religious group, besides Jews of course, that was represented there mainly because of their religious beliefs(?)

For example, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priest_Barracks_of_Dachau_Concentration_Camp) 2720 clerics were incarcerated at Dachau.

**The question I wanted to ask is:** what color triangles were assigned to the members of other religious groups, i.e. those that were neither Jews or JWs?

Comment: At least the Roman Catholic clergy may have been imprisoned not so much because of religious beliefs but because of political reasons. They were politically active (not just as representatives of the Vatican but also otherwise in their home countries) during WW2 and before. Thus they would not have had a "Roman Catholic"-specific color but more of a political color.

Comment: For example...according to some sources such as [this one](https://adarapress.com/2015/05/15/roman-catholic-priests-ran-half-the-concentration-camps-in-croatia/) and the book "Unholy Trinity: The Vatican, The Nazis, and The Swiss Banks" (M. Aarons and J. Loftus, 1998) the Roman Catholic clergy together with the [Ustaše](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usta%C5%A1e) movement was involved in running concentration camps in Croatia during WW2.

Comment: You might also want to check my answer from 2015 to a similar question. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23997/what-were-the-52-kinds-of-victims-persecuted-by-the-nazis/23999#23999

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to The [United States Holocaust Memorial Museum](https://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10005378#) site:

> Criminals were marked with green inverted triangles, political
>   prisoners with red, "asocials" (including Roma, nonconformists,
>   vagrants, and other groups) with black or—in the case of Roma in some
>   camps—brown triangles. Homosexuals were identified with pink triangles
>   and Jehovah's Witnesses with purple ones. Non-German prisoners were
>   identified by the first letter of the German name for their home
>   country, which was sewn onto their badge. The two triangles forming
>   the Jewish star badge would both be yellow unless the Jewish prisoner
>   was included in one of the other prisoner categories. A Jewish
>   political prisoner, for example, would be identified with a yellow
>   triangle beneath a red triangle.

There is also an [image/ chart](https://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/media_da.php?ModuleId=10005378&MediaId=5037) on the site. It is also shown on the [Nazi concentration camp badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_concentration_camp_badge), which has quite a bit of other info concerning these markings.

[image]

-update-

After some further information added in the question, the red triangle is listed at [this blog site](http://tspatton.blogspot.com/2011/01/dachau-camp-special-persons-cells-and.html) as being applied to "dissenting Christian priests". So no special color was awarded to them, as mentioned in comments,it appears they were classified as general political prisoners along with:

> political prisoners: social democrats, socialists, trade unionists,
>   Freemasons, communists, and anarchists.

---

Another work, [Jehovah's Witnesses in National Socialist Concentration Camps](https://biblicalstudies.org.uk/pdf/rss/34-2_089.pdf), mentions *small numbers* of other denominations being classed with purple triangles:

> The concentration camp prisoner category 'Bible Student' at times
>   apparently included a few members from small Bible Student splinter
>   groups, as well as adherents of other religious groups which played
>   only a secondary role during the time of the National Socialist
>   regime, such as Adventists, Baptists and the New Apostolic community

---

So it appears different color badges, but still within the original color selections, may have been applied to various religious denominations.